# How to remove and add completly new db.sqlite3 to django project written in pycharm?

Tags: python, sql, django

How to remove and add completly new **db.sqlite3** database to **django** project written in **pycharm**?
I did something wrong and I need completelty new database. The 'flush' command just removes data from databse but it't dosent remove tables schema. So the question is how to get get back my databse to begin point(no data, no sql table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A SQLite database is just a file. To drop the database, simply remove the file.

When using SQLite, `python manage.py migrate` will automatically create the database if it doesn't exist.

Comment: It is true. I accepted this answer. Thank you for your help!